# Dynamiclly add series with a check box list

Tags: extjs

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
fields:['date', 'sales','vehicle_id'],
data: [
    {date:'2014-03-20', sales: 1500, vehicle_id: 1},
    {date:'2014-03-20', sales: 2000, vehicle_id: 2},
    {date:'2014-03-20', sales: 2500, vehicle_id: 3},
    {date:'2014-03-21', sales: 2000, vehicle_id: 1},
    {date:'2014-03-21', sales: 1200, vehicle_id: 2},
    {date:'2014-03-21', sales: 1500, vehicle_id: 3},
    {date:'2014-03-22', sales: 1600, vehicle_id: 1},
    {date:'2014-03-22', sales: 3600, vehicle_id: 2},
    {date:'2014-03-22', sales: 4300, vehicle_id: 3},
    {date:'2014-03-23', sales: 1100, vehicle_id: 1},
    {date:'2014-03-23', sales: 1200, vehicle_id: 2},
    {date:'2014-03-23', sales: 4500, vehicle_id: 3},
]
});
```

[image]

Left panel have a Grid Panel with a Check box,
When the first row check box are checked will get the `vehicle_id` from JsonStore,

Example: First grid panel row `vehicle_id` is `3` when check box are checked,
will select the store where `vehicle_id` is equal `3` then add the dynamic series in right panel's Chart

### Question

1)how to select the `vehicle_id` equal `3` only?
2)and add the series with vehicle_id = 3 data into chart? actually is not add, is append, when the chart are having Series, then want to Append the new series.

This is a very complex in coding, have any solution?

p/s : Date will be in X Axis, Sales will be as Y axis

this my how my layout code, but without jsonstore inside

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel2', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    height: 519,
    width: 804,
    title: 'My Panel',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    height: 441,
                    layout: {
                        align: 'stretch',
                        type: 'hbox'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridpanel',
                            height: 250,
                            width: 464,
                            header: false,
                            title: 'My Grid Panel',
                            columns: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                    dataIndex: 'string',
                                    text: 'Plat No'
                                }
                            ],
                            selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {

                            }),
                            dockedItems: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                                    dock: 'top',
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'datefield',
                                            fieldLabel: 'Start',
                                            labelWidth: 50
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'datefield',
                                            fieldLabel: 'End',
                                            labelWidth: 50
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'button',
                                            text: 'Generate'
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'chart',
                            height: 250,
                            width: 408,
                            animate: true,
                            insetPadding: 20,
                            axes: [
                                {
                                    type: 'Category',
                                    fields: [
                                        'x'
                                    ],
                                    title: 'Date Axis',
                                    position: 'bottom'
                                },
                                {
                                    type: 'Numeric',
                                    fields: [
                                        'y'
                                    ],
                                    title: 'Sales Axis',
                                    position: 'left'
                                }
                            ],
                            series: [
                                {
                                    type: 'line',
                                    xField: 'x',
                                    yField: 'y',
                                    smooth: 3
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

Comment: where is the chart code?

Comment: @Oğuz Çelikdemir No Idea, how to add the series dynamically. any solution?

Comment: I need to know chart code to be able give you an answer.

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir Added, but dont have jsonstore inside

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you want to group vehicles based on the selection then show in the chart, right?

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir Yes, Group by `vehicle_ID` from jsonstore, and show in the chart when the check box are checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filterBy function](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy)

```
store.filterBy(this, function(record, id) {
  if(rec.get('vehicle_id') === "selected_id") {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

You can also use renderer function.
I am not sure about this approach, but it is worth trying.

```
series: [
{
  type: 'line',
  xField: 'x',
  yField: 'y',
  smooth: 3,
  renderer:  function(sprite, record, attributes, index, store) {
    //Access store and select related elements
  }
}
]
```

Comment: and how to dynamically add the Series, this is the problem

Comment: Did you try `renderer` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working Example:

[Filter Chart based on the store value](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4kv)

Basically, you can call store's `filter` function by related data field.

```
handler: function() {
    /**
     * here we are defining a variable which will hold 
     * the vehicle value. In reality, you should bound
     * this value with your combobox. Whenever user
     * select the checkbox, you can call a special function
     * like below
     */
    var vehicle = 3;
    myStore.clearFilter(true);
    myStore.filter('vehicle_id', vehicle);
}
```

Comment: then how about when selected 2 rows, mean 2 vehicle_id at the same time, because check box can be checked 2, or 3 .how to add multiple series line ?

Comment: if first row and second row check box are checked, then chart must be 2 series line. how to dynamically add series line with store filter by `vehicle_id` ?

Comment: if 2 check box are checked, mean are having 2 series line in a chart.

Comment: Totally different thing! You want to filter series data then want to add new series. So, you should modify your store data first than create a chart in normal way.

Comment: please see my question, ok. if modify store data first, how to add the series by  grouping `vehicle_id` , this is the problem.

Comment: Please help, need it so much

Comment: Please, how to group by vehicle_id in jsonstore?